# "Basic ideas" as a concept in teaching maths?

Tags: teaching

In Germany there exists a concept whose name might be translated as "basic ideas." The core of the concept is to offer the students an idea of what they are learning, e.g. in the context of derivatives of a function, to interpret the derivative as instantaneous rate of change and so on. Is there a comparable concept in the US?

Greetings, Rico

Comment: "basic ideas" is a rather vague "category", please define what you consider "basic ideas", and know that others may not agree with what you consider "basic ideas".

Answer (score 2):

Most U.S. middle-school or high-school textbooks have a box labelled "Objectives" that lay out the basic ideas in the coming chapter or section. Many textbooks also begin a section with a thought question that introduces one or more basic idea of the section. The question is open-ended and thought-provoking and cannot be answered until some basic ideas are mastered.

There are so many examples--look at just about any recent U.S. textbook for an example.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It isn‘t that easy to look up such a textbook, because I‘m from Germany and do not have access to a hardcopy. But maybe there are softcopys available online. Thank you for that hint.